# Как переместить ext3 том?

Tags: ubuntu, ext3

есть вот такой ext3 том и свободное место

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проблема в том что ничто не может его переместить, ни управление компютером, ни NIUBI, ни gparted.
надо поменять их местами

Comment: объясните пожалуйста без слишком сложных терминов, я в этом не очень сильно разбираюсь

Comment: загрузите компьютер с live-usb и перемещайет сколько влезет.